# Formatting a long timestamp into a Date with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am pulling a long timestamp from a database, but want to present it as a Date using Tags only, no embedded java in the JSP.
 I've created my own tag to do this because I was unable to get the parseDate and formatDate tags to work, but that's not to say they don't work.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parseDate and formatDate tags work, but they work with Date objects.
You can call new java.util.Date(longvalue) to get a date object, then pass that to the standard tag.

somewhere other than the jsp create your date object.

```
long longvalue = ...;//from database.
java.util.Date dateValue = new java.util.Date(longvalue);
request.setAttribute("dateValue", dateValue);
```

put it on the request and then you can access it in your tag like this.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"/>
```

Comment: I needed to change it to new java.util.Date(longvalue*1000); since Java is expecting miliseconds if anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 52):

You can avoid having to make any changes to your Servlet by creating a date object within the JSP using the `jsp:useBean` and `jsp:setProperty` tags to set the time of newly created date object to that of the time stamp. For example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${timestampValue}"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"/>
```

Comment: This is good if your looping through a list and you need to do this on a property of each item.

Comment: this is not work for me . it just display 12/31/1969 16:00 for all value i passed in