# Looking for JSTL Taglib calculate seconds between two dates

Tags: time, jstl, taglib

I'm looking for a taglib to use for calculating how many seconds there was between two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do that with EL:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now1" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:useBean id="now2" class="java.utli.Date" />
The difference is: ${now1.time/1000) - (now2.time/1000)}
```

That's just a simple compilable example -- in real life, the two dates would hold different values.

Comment: I didn't use this solution, wrote my own taglib instead. But this is an alternative and working.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an ancient question, but how would I go about creating the Date object from an existing value?

Comment: You can use formatDate and parseDate from the JSTL core library.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75489/formatting-a-long-timestamp-into-a-date-with-jstl