# JSTL - use formatDate with a java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, servlets, timestamp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a tag with the following:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty"%>
<%@ attribute name="timestamp" required="true" type="java.sql.Timestamp"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date" />
<c:if test="${not empty timestamp}">
    <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${timestamp}" />
    <span title="${timestamp}"> <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}"
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" /> </span>
</c:if>
```

I get the following error however:

> Error 500: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 5/1/12 10:36 AM of type class java.sql.Timestamp to long

I was trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628641/38743) to convert a timestamp to a date in JSTL, so I wouldn't have change anything in my servlet.  How can I convert a `java.sql.Timestamp` to a date so that `formatDate` can work with it, using JSTL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass in [`Timestamp#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29).

```html
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${timestamp.time}" />
```

But this makes all no sense. The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is already a subclass of [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). So this should also do:

```html
<%@ attribute name="timestamp" required="true" type="java.sql.Timestamp"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<c:if test="${not empty timestamp}">
    <span title="${timestamp}"><fmt:formatDate value="${timestamp}"
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" /></span>
</c:if>
```

I'd by the way also change your models to declare the property as `java.util.Date` instead. You should not use `java.sql.Timestamp` in the model and view, but only in the data layer. You don't need to convert `ResultSet#getTimestamp()` to `java.util.Date` by parsing/formatting. Just upcasting is sufficient.

E.g.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class SomeModel {

    private Date somefield;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
someModel.setSomefield(resultSet.getTimestamp("somefield"));
```

Comment: Oh, derp.  I never tried just using `formatDate` directly on the timestamp, since I saw questions online about having to convert a timestamp to a date to use it with `formatDate`.  Thanks!

Comment: Other questions were talking about timestamp as in a `long` value indicating the epoch time. But you actually already have a `java.sql.Timestamp` which in turn is thus already a subclass of `java.util.Date`.