# Timestamp to date conversion failure in jsp/jstl

Tags: jsp, date, timestamp, jstl

I'm trying to convert some timestamp values from a collection to a human readable date format.
Within a jsp, I've coded this loop:

```
  <c:forEach items="${tokenCollection}" var="tokenCollection" varStatus="status">
      <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" />
      <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" /> 
      <!-- Correctly prints values as "40aa4ab4-f6c1-458a-9v3d-5d13b872d9c2" -->
      <c:out value="${tokenCollection.value.value}"/>
      <!-- Correctly prints values as "1378722681816" -->
      <c:out value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}"/>
  </c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately, all I get by running it is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /session_management.jsp at line 36

33:       <p>Dati di sessione - utente "<c:out value="${username}" />"</p>
34:       
35:       <c:forEach items="${tokenCollection}" var="tokenCollection" varStatus="status">
36:           <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" />
37:           <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />                      
38:           <c:out value="${tokenCollection.value.value}"/>
39:           <c:out value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}"/>

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}"
```

As stated in the comments, values are retreived correctly, so ${tokenCollection.value.timestamp} is by all means a timestamp (like 1378722681816). Still, I can't figure out how to fix this issue, or what exactly I'm being wront at. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

jsp:setProperty is for setting a property on a bean; the bean needs to be declared first using jsp:useBean.  This will call the setTime method on the com.something.className class; it won't create a dateValue variable.

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="com.something.className" scope="page" />
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" />
```

You can use your value directly:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

Or if you really need it in different variable. use c:set:

```
<c:set var="dateValue" value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. By directly using <fmt:formatDate value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" /> I get: Unable to convert string "${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "value": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

Comment: The error message means fmt:formatDate expects a date object (java.util.Date), but you're giving it a string.  You'll need to convert your string to a date first using fmt:parseDate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75489/formatting-a-long-timestamp-into-a-date-with-jstl  Maybe that's where your jsp:setProperty came from?

    <jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${timestampValue}" />
    <fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />

Comment: `<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date" />` 
`<jsp:setProperty name="dateObj" property="time" value="${tokenCollection.value.timestamp}" />`  
`<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObj}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />`

Comment: Thanks, I had already read that other question but unfortunately hadn't worked for me. Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to be working either, as I get a NullPointerException at the setProperty line

Comment: Can you see any more info about the exception? Can you print out the parameter you're passing to the setProperty? I can't seem to get the code to format properly, but this worked for me: 
`<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/fmt" %>
<c:set var="dateValue" value="1378722681816 " />
<jsp:useBean id="dateObj" class="java.util.Date" /> 
<jsp:setProperty name="dateObj" property="time" value="${dateValue}" /> 
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObj}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />`

Comment: Hi @kielni, apart from not being able to use your taglibs (doesn't seem to be there anymore), I tried to put your code in but unfortunately didn't work. Here's full Tomcat stack trace: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6299368/Apache%20Tomcat_7.0.42%20-%20Error%20report.htm

Comment: there shouldn't be a space in the dateValue: `<c:set var="dateValue" value="1378722681816" />`